# Distributing $4$ different red balls and four different green balls to $4$ people

Tags: combinatorics, permutations

Let $m$ denote the number of ways in which $4$ different balls of green colour and $4$ different balls of red colour can be distributed equally among $4$ persons if each person has balls of the same colour and $n$ be the corresponding figure when all the four persons have balls of different colours. Find $\frac{m+n}{132}$.

I've tried it using distribution theorem $\dfrac{m}{132} = \dfrac{8!}{2!\cdot2!\cdot2!\cdot2!\cdot2^4}\cdot\dfrac{4!}{132}$
but while calculating $\dfrac{n}{132}$ I am getting answer in decimal. Please help me in this?

Comment: Could you please explain a little bit about *distribution theorem*? And why the denominator is $132$?

Comment: Certainly $m \neq \frac{8!\cdot 4!}{2!\cdot2!\cdot2!\cdot2!\cdot2^4},$ so the application of the "distribution theorem," whatever that is, appears to have been done incorrectly.

Comment: How to apply distribution theorem in this question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't know the theorem, but I'll give it a try:

m:

$$\textrm{(who get green)}\cdot\textrm{(which two for each whom)}$$
$${4\choose2}\cdot({4\choose2}{2\choose2}\cdot{4\choose2}{2\choose2}),$$
which is $6\cdot6\cdot6=216.$

n:

$$\textrm{(deliver red ones)}\cdot\textrm{(deliver green ones)}$$
$$4!\cdot4!=24\cdot24=576.$$

so the answer could be $\frac{216+576}{132}=6.$